# Maven Java SpringCould not find artifact org.vaadin.crudui:crudui:pom:4.3.0 in central

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a problem
version does not work on the latest version springboot 2.4.1 :(

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.crudui</groupId>
   <artifactId>crudui</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

vaadin version

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: What is not working exactly? Did you try other versions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Others may be able to help you better if you can include example code of what you are trying to accomplish and what you expect the result to be. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for additional guidance.

Comment: yes i used 2.3.7 etc. and i still have problem